# How to amend a part of a text file when the size of the input may change

Tags: vb.net, file, text, listbox

vb.net

Hi all.

I have a text file like follows:

[Sec A]
123ABC
456DEF
(and some more entries like this)

[Sec B]
789ABC
3245DEF
(and some more entries like this)

[Sec C]
ABC
.. and other entries in here.

I am trying to WRITE to the file, but the difficulty I am having is I want to replace just one part of the text file and not all.

E.g.

I have a listbox with items on my form (ListB), and when I click the button, I want to replace the data under the [Sec B] header but BEFORE the [Sec C] header.

Now, sometimes this data maybe just 1 item, but other times, it could be 10 items, and I don't want to overwrite the [Sec C] header.

Any info please appreciated, as I have been trying for hours to get it to work!

thanks in advance.

Comment: Where are the values to replace the entries for Section B coming from?

Comment: Hi Mary, they are in ListBoxB as Items.

Comment: You don't edit the file. You read the file content in as one or more `String` objects, manipulate that data as required and then you write the data out to file. They are separate and independent steps so you should handle the separately and independently. You can manipulate `Strings` without files and you can work with files without manipulating `Strings`. This is the #1 reason beginners have issues: they don't separate discrete problems and try to handle them as a single unit. ALWAYS divide and conquer.

Comment: @jmcilhinney while I don't disagree with you, much easy to tackle the string manipulation and file handling as separate and independent, it's not always clear cut as this especially to a beginner who is still figuring out where to start and struggling to know what to even put into google to get decent search results

Comment: @Hursey, *"it's not always clear cut as this especially to a beginner"*. That's probably why I explained it in my comment. If I point out that someone is doing something wrong, it's not an accusation that they are a bad person. It's to indicate what they should avoid doing in future. If you don't know what mistakes you're making then you're doomed to repeat them. If you do know the mistake you made in a specific case then you can change your approach and hopefully solve the problem for yourself. That's the point. Assume that criticism is criticism rather than an attack.

Comment: Hi, thanks, I have solved it now. I used a different method where each section was put on its own line instead and then we just remove the entire line and write it back in again with the new data.

Comment: To the original question, you're effectively looking for record-based processing of text files.  I don't think there's any built-in support for this, so you would need to roll your own (which it looks like you did).

Comment: @Craig Didn't we have random access files in the olden days? Can't remember how they were accessed but it was before vb had database access built in.

Comment: @Mary Record-based file formats aren't a new thing (they go back a lot farther than VB) but if I remember right, they're generally designed as binary (non-text) files with a specific structure to enable navigation.